# Crystal Report Asking parameter again

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-server

Dear all I am working on an asp .net application in which I am using crystal report for showing reports.

In my application everything works fine including the reports. The real problem comes when I start clicking on the crystal report toolbar. If I click on any buttons on the crystal report tool bar like (Export, next page ...etc.) it is asking parameters again. Is there any way so that that the crystal report viewer does not ask the parameter that I have already given ?

I have also given true for the property `reuseparametervaluesonrefresh`. i am passing parameters to the report document.

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument(); 
rd.SetParameterValue("@Date", Request["Date"]);  CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
```

Comment: I would suspect that your viewer control makes use of full page post backs for proper operation, most of them do. Unless there is a version that supports MVC specifically you will have to do some adjusting to get it to work. I assume this is an mvc application, not a web forms, since you tagged it as such.

Comment: no bro. its not an mvc application. its a webfrom  application using master and content pages.

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple reason for prompt, is that problem solved? If not, let me know, I will post answer

Comment: problem solved thanks @ItiTyagi

Answer (score 0):

try to change Crystal Report Parameter type from **Date** to **String**.